# Uncaught ReferenceError: topPos is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am facing a issue with my code.  its work fine in html. when i convert to Wordpress i receive a error when i press button to show bottom hidden info.

and this error shwoing after click the button
`Uncaught ReferenceError: topPos is not defined`

here is my code

```
 $(".info-data").hide();
    var activeInfoData = $(".info-nav .active a").attr("href");
    $(activeVehicleData).show();

$('.info-nav-scroll').click(function () {
    var direction = $(this).data('direction');
    var scrollHeight = $('.info-nav li').height() + 1;
    var navHeight = $('#info-nav-container').height() + 1;
    var actTopPos = $(".info-nav").position().top;

    // Scroll Down
    if (direction == 'down' && -navHeight <= actTopPos - (scrollHeight * 2)) {
        topPos = actTopPos - scrollHeight;
        $(".info-nav").css('top', topPos);
    }

    // Scroll Up
    if (direction == 'up' && 0 > actTopPos) {
        topPos = actTopPos + scrollHeight;
        $(".info-nav").css('top', topPos);
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: add `var topPos = '';` just after `var actTopPos = $(".info-nav").position().top;`

Comment: Provide line throwing this error

Comment: Just wondering, are using strict mode?

Comment: please update as answer how you fix your issue ?? dose any answer help you or found solution at your own ?

Comment: but i have faced  another issue  when i click button its need minimum 11 info list. but i dont want to set minimum 11 list.  if bellow 11 a blank space shwoing. here i have set 9 list and now showing 2 blank list :(  http://prntscr.com/7dqsup

Comment: @A.Wolff yes i am using strict mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define `topPos` variable in side or out side of click function like below

```
var topPos = '';  // or  var topPos = 0;
var direction = $(this).data('direction');
var scrollHeight = $('.info-nav li').height() + 1;
var navHeight = $('#info-nav-container').height() + 1;
var actTopPos = $(".info-nav").position().top;
```

You can read more about [scope of variable in Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Comment: No, it would define it in local scope

Comment: @A.Wolff this variable only used in side click function so is in necessary to define as Global varible ?

Comment: But OP posted code shouldnt throw error only if no `if` condition is reached then `topPos ` is undefined. I guess OP is trying to use this variable outside click handler because it looks like he has posted all click handler code. I could be wrong

Comment: @A.Wolff . ok i have added this link in my answer http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp  so OP can understand scop of variables in javascript . also this error may be occer because of other two varible . here we are not sure which varible is give perfect result

Comment: I forgot but in strict mode OP's code would throw an error and then your solution would handle it

Comment: its work great. 
but i have faced  another issue  when i click button its need minimum 11 info list. but i dont want to set minimum 11 list.  if bellow 11 a blank space shwoing. here i have set 9 list and now showing 2 blank list :(  http://prntscr.com/7dqsup

Comment: @A.Wolff I am alws use script mode. without strict error will be different.

Comment: thats fine .. but i can't understand your second issue ?? i hvae post only answer of your issue you mention in question :)

Answer (score 1):

in the click event itself declare the `topPos` variable and since it is height assign 0 to it (a number). If you intend to use it every where then remove `var` from the declaration to give it a global scope.

```
   $('.info-nav-scroll').click(function () {
    var topPos = 0; // declare as topPos = 0; if you intend to use it as a global variable
    var direction = $(this).data('direction');
    var scrollHeight = $('.info-nav li').height() + 1;
    var navHeight = $('#info-nav-container').height() + 1;
    var actTopPos = $(".info-nav").position().top;
```

Comment: No, it would define it in local scope

Comment: @A.Wolff, yes i mentioned that in the answer about how to use it in local and global scope